# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'metadata')

Tags: javascript, next.js, layout

I am getting an error when setting up a responsive navbar. The error is "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'metadata')".

My layout.js looks the following

```
import Head from "next/head";

function NavItem(props) {
  const { title, url, isSelected } = props;
  return (
    <li>
      <a
        className={`block px-3 py-2 transition hover:text-teal-500 ${
          isSelected ? "text-teal-500" : ""
        }`}
        href={url}
      >
        {title}
      </a>
    </li>
  );
}

function Navbar(props) {
  return (
    <div className="flex justify-center mx-auto max-w-7xl h-16 pt-6">
      <nav>
        <ul className="flex rounded-full bg-white/90 px-3 text-sm font-medium text-zinc-800 shadow-lg shadow-zinc-800/5 ring-1 ring-zinc-900/5 backdrop-blur">
          <NavItem
            title={"About Me"}
            url={"/"}
            isSelected={props.pageId == "about_me"}
          />
        
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
}

function FooterLink(props) {
  let { url, text } = props;
  return (
    <a className="transition hover:text-teal-500" href={url}>
      {text}
    </a>
  );
}

function Footer() {
  return (
    <footer className="pt-6 px-8 pb-16 border-t mt-10">
      <div className="flex justify-between gap-6">
        <div className="flex gap-6 text-sm font-medium text-zinc-600">
          <FooterLink text={"About Me"} url={"/"} />
          {/* <FooterLink text={"Projects"} url={"/projects"} />
          <FooterLink text={"Essays"} url={"/essays"} /> */}
        </div>
        <p className="text-sm text-zinc-400">
          © 2023 Grace Huang. All rights reserved.
        </p>
      </div>
    </footer>
  );
}

export default function Layout({ children }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
        <title>{children.props.metadata.title}</title>
        <meta
          name="description"
          content={children.props.metadata.description}
        />
        {/* Open Graph tags */}
        <meta property="og:title" content={children.props.metadata.title} />
        <meta
          property="og:description"
          content={children.props.metadata.description}
        />
        <meta
          property="og:image"
          content={children.props.metadata.openGraph.image}
        />
        <meta
          property="og:url"
          content={children.props.metadata.openGraph.url}
        />
      </Head>
      <Navbar pageId={children.props.pageId} />
      <main>{children}</main>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}
```

Can someone explain me, why metadata isn't found? Maybe I made a mistake when going back from typescript. But the props definition is done in NavItem.

Thanks!

Comment: The value `children.props` does not exist or is not yet populated. You should use nullish coalescing (eg. `children?.props?.metadata`) or an `if` evaluation to check if `children?.props` exists before attempting to access its descendants.